# adding images to the ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html

i want to add image  again in the ck editor  when i click on button "add gap"

here is my code

```
<div class="control-group" align="left" style="float: left" onselect="selectText()">
    <textarea name="editor1" id="myTextarea"><p>please type<img src="img/gap-placeholder.png"/></p> </textarea>
</div>

<div style="float: left;margin-left: 5px">
    <input type="button"  value="Add Gap"  onclick="insertText();"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to add image. But your function name is insertText(). Confusing!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try the insertHTML function for ckeditor.

```
var editor = var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance;
var data = '<img src="img/gap-placeholder.png"/>';
editor.insertHtml(data, 'unfiltered_html');
```